Can I link two stepper controllers and motors of different types to the same step signal outputs from a control board?
I need stepper motors of different amps and weights to mirror each other to +/- 5% total precision.
Can there be problems if I use the same step-signal pins from a control board towards two different stepper controllers? I'm planning on buying a low cost ESP32 / Arduino PCB for it.

what will you do if one of the motors misses a step?

If the motors are the same number of steps / revolution (that is, the same step angle), you should be able to control them with the same set of signals and have the motors follow each other in perfect sync.
One thing to watch out for is, if the motors are very different in size you could have a problem if you try to push the step rate too high. A bigger motor has more inertia than a smaller one so will have a lower max step rate.
Also, mind that different torque loads will influence the step rate, and that resonance issues can come up.
More here: https://motioncontrolproducts.com/resources/stepper-motor-selection-guide
